# mysql group by on sum column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am having a scenario where students of a college do a research on a subject. Each subject has some value (marks) for it. A student can do research on multiple subjects.

I have the following table hierarchy:

```
student (s)
---------------
student_id  subject_id

1           2
2           1
2           3
3           1
3           3
4           2
4           3
.....


research_subjects (r)
-----------------------------
id      value

1       5
2       10
3       20
4       40
....
```

Now i am fetching the student records along with their total research value with this query:

**`select student_id, sum(r.value) as total from student s inner join research_subjects r on s.subject_id=r.id group by student_id`**

This gives results like the following:

```
student_id  total

1           10
2           25
3           25
4           30
```

As you see, the results are grouped by **student_id**. But what i want is to group the results by **total** value. So i want to get rid of duplicate rows for the **total**, in the output. (i.e., have only 1 record with the total=25).

I tried using: **group by total** in the query (instead of **group by student_id**), but it gives an error.
Is there any other way of grouping the results by the column that contains 'sum' value?

Comment: you can not group by an alias, try group by sum(r.value)

Comment: For duplicates sum value which student id you expect from query to return ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid It can return any student id, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(student_id), total
  from ( 
    select student_id, sum(r.value) as total 
     from student s 
     inner 
     join research r on s.subject_id=r.id group by student_id
     ) s2
 group by total
```

Comment: This worked out well. I have edited the answer with the working query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Count(student_id) as students, total
from
(
    select student_id, sum(r.value) as total 
    from student s inner join research r on s.subject_id=r.id 
    group by student_id
) s
group by total
```

Or this:

```
 select Min(student_id) as student_id, total
    from
    (
        select student_id, sum(r.value) as total 
        from student s inner join research r on s.subject_id=r.id 
        group by student_id
    ) s
    group by total
```

Comment: Even this worked, but i had to add an alias for the inner query, as i got a warning: Every derived table must have its own alias.